# Dispatching action with 3rd-party callback

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

In my app I have a worker Saga which calls a method from a 3rd-party library. The 3rd-party library is a payment service (Zuora), and the method initializes an iframe form and renders it within a component. The 3rd-party library method requires a callback function, which is called when the iframe form is submitted.

Here's a simplified view of the saga:

```
function* render(action) {
  try {
    const callback = function(response) {
      if (response.success) {
        // DISPATCH ACTION HERE
      }
    }

    ZUORALIBRARY.render(callback);
    yield put({...action, type: RENDER_SUCCESS});

  } catch (e) {
    yield put({...action, type: RENDER_FAIL, errors: e});
  }
}
```

I'd like to dispatch an action within the callback but have had no luck in making it work. This has involved trying to make the callback function into a generator and using `yield`/`put`. I've also read this approach may be an antipattern.

Is there a different/better way to handle this?

Comment: When I have to handle 3rd party libraries such as loggers, analytics, etc. I tend to create a `middleware` responsible of interact with those, in this way I can separate the logic of the application from the logic of those third party. So, ideally, you could dispatch your action from the middleware, considering that there you access to the `dispatch` function.

Comment: Great, do you have any resources you can point me to?

Comment: I personally started with the official documentation [here](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html#seven-examples). It's really simple! After that, I just started making my own personal changes. If you want to understand more about middlewares, you can read the whole page

Answer (score 0):

What about doing something like this

```
import { call, put } from "redux-saga/effects";

function renderIframe() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ZUORALIBRARY.render(response => {
      if (response.success) {
        resolve(response);
      } else {
        reject();
      }
    });
  });
}

function* render(action) {
  try {
    const result = yield call(renderIframe);
    yield put({ ...action, type: RENDER_SUCCESS });
  } catch (e) {
    yield put({ ...action, type: RENDER_FAIL, errors: e });
  }
}
```